# Wordpress doesnt load js file

Tags: wordpress

When I add the js file by html command, it loads but when I add it by wp command, it doesnt load.

```
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<?php
    wp_register_script( 'foo-stylesa1-slick-jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foo-stylesa1-slick-jquery' );
?>
```

I use above code snippet in my 2 plugin at the same time.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60056/enqueue-jquery-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You have to use complete register script function, since many times wordpress loads script above jquery and due to this scripts not work.

```
wp_register_script( 'someScript-js', '/someScript.js' , '', '', true );
```

Here **true** is used for loading scripts to the footer section after jquery enqueued.

Or you can directly use jquery enqueue function without loading its from external.

wp_register_script('jquery');

This will directly include jquery for your website.